# 2 animations working strange together...?

Tags: css, animation

As described in the title im trying to make two animations sync... 
I will link both individual animations in 2 fiddles so you can see each of them and i will also link a fiddle to my weird result..

1st fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oxc12av7/

2nd fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5knf0xtr/

This is my code to connect them: (chrome only)

```css
#pot{
  bottom:15%;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-animation:linear infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-name: run, swap;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
  animation:linear infinite alternate;
  animation-name: run, swap;
  animation-duration: 8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes run {
  0% { left: 0;}
  50%{ left : 82%;}
  100%{ left: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes swap {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
    100%{-webkit-transform: scaleX 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
  }
}
```

So you can see that it works the first time to mirror it but the next time it doesn't... https://jsfiddle.net/j3c1rqb0/
any ideas why?
The potatos face should be looking like this..

-> -> -> -> -> -> -> -> ->

<- <- <- <- <- <- <- <- <-
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by sync, maybe a GIF of the animation would help us?
Like this: http://i.imgur.com/MVKryob.gifv ?

Comment: yeah exactly like that, but it should not turn around while moving, it is suppossed to switch scaleX instant @Maverick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to remove `alternate` from `-webkit-animation:linear infinite alternate;`

```css
#pot{
bottom:15%;
position:absolute;
-webkit-animation:linear infinite;
-webkit-animation-name: run, swap;
-webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
}
```

and you missed `}` somewhere in the keyframe.

look here: https://jsfiddle.net/wsp2z5py/

And here is [alternative keyframe](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnz1p1ke/)

Comment: Thanks alot, really good answer and also another way to solve it!

Comment: +1 especially for the alternate answer. I think it is better to implement this as one single animation than with two.

Answer (score 1):

I think you neet to remove 50% from run, try this:

```css
#pot {
  bottom: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: run, swap;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes run {
  0% {
 left: 0;
  }
  50% {
 left: 82%;
  }
  100% {
 left: 0%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes swap {
 0% {-webkit-transform: scaleX 1;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);}
 50% {-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);}
 100%{-webkit-transform: scaleX 1;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);}
  }
```

```html
<div id = "pot">
<img src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgNyF.png?s=328&g=1" width = 100px height =100px>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it wasn't the way it should move,

Comment: I had misunderstood what you wanted, but after your last edit I got it clearly. Try again.